# Updating UITableView's imageView/detailTextLabel

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I'm using UITableView to display multiple rows of data: textLabel.text for name, imageView to show status (online/offline), detailTextLabel for additional info.

ex. in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checking.png"];
cell.textLabel.text = @"NAME";
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Checking...";
```

How can I update the imageView.image and detailTextLabel.text from another function. Is there a UITableView method? 
I am guessing I need to use IndexPath row to target the cell. Perhaps assign tags for each imageView and detailTextLabel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your better option is to update the data in your model and then ask the table view to `reloadData` (or, if you specifically know which row(s) are updated, `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`).

This maintains the integrity of your data model and is the simplest code to manage the view.

Comment: But how do I target a row (IndexPath.row) and update the detailTextLabel and imageView.image? Can you provide some sample code? Thanks.

Comment: You are implementing the table view data source methods right? tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Yes, I ended up using something like this: UITableViewCell *cell0 = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]]; Where indexPathForRow and inSection are fixed. Frm that I was able to update cell0 like this cell0.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"connected.png"];

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use properties like this :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *textLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *detailTextLabel;
```

Then you add this properties to your cell as you did :

```
cell.imageView.image = image;
cell.textLabel.text = textLabel;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = detailTextLabel;
```

Whenever you update your data, you call the method which reload your cell (with the array containing the indexPath of the cell you want to reload):

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Comment: Also not working: [self.tableView beginUpdates];
 detailTextLabel1 = @"New detail text";
 [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
 [self.tableView endUpdates];
 [self.tableView reloadData];